# Postscript pound sterling sign

Tags: postscript

I have a postscript file with this in it:

```
/Helvetica findfont 12 scalefont setfont
(£1.60) show
```

When I view the file is appears as

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLWa0.png

The same thing happens with any of the default fonts I try.

How can I get rid of the incorrect character at the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered my issue, the document encoding was set to UTF-8, works fine if I set it to ANSI.

Comment: That should not make any difference. UTF8 is a superset of ANSI for these characters.

Comment: Not too sure why it works, I changed the encoding to ANSI in Notepad++, the "hidden" character was visible and I was able to remove it.

Comment: That would be a Notepad++ bug then.

Comment: UTF8 is not a superset of ANSI. There are some characters, including £, which are encoded as different byte sequences in UTF8 and ANSI. Puppy, you may be thinking of ASCII. UTF8 is indeed a superset of ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-encode the Helvetica font so that the /sterling name is at the index in the font's Encoding array that you want to use. If the font doesn't have a /sterling glyph it will use /.notdef instead, which is normally a non-marking glyph for PostScript fonts.

As I think I've mentioned before, John Deubert of Acumen Training has published an excellent series of articles here:

http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html

You should look at the November and December 2001 PostScript articles.

Comment: I tried the code from the articles but couldn't get it to work. I also tried loading a different font from a pfa file which does have /sterling defined but still got an unwanted character before it seen here: https://i.imgur.com/RSeutWh.png

Comment: Discovered my issue, the document encoding was set to UTF-8, works fine if I set it to ANSI.